# fcitx doesn't work with Sublime Text 3 and RStudio

Tags: sublime-text, fcitx, rstudio

I tried to use fcitx to type Vietnamese. It works with most programs including LibreOffice and Atom. However, it doesn't work with Sublime Text 3 and RStudio. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: It is a well-known limitation for Sublime Text, you can search some dirty fix for it on the net. I'm not using RStudio, not sure the reason.

Comment: https://github.com/lyfeyaj/sublime-text-imfix

Comment: all I could find on rstudio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205605748-Using-RStudio-0-99-with-Fctix-on-Linux

Answer (score 3):

There is a fix to do this on [github](https://github.com/lyfeyaj/sublime-text-imfix). Make sure your system is updated and the commands to install this fix are (I assume you have both sublime and fcitx installed) ...

```
git clone https://github.com/lyfeyaj/sublime-text-imfix.git
cd sublime-text-imfix
./sublime-imfix
```

**Important:** There is a note in the link that you need to start sublime from commandline (using `subl` command) for this to work.